# Is there a wx.EVT_CHAR or event.GetKeyCode() equivalent for wxPython( Phoenix )?

Tags: python, events, user-interface, event-handling, wxpython

I just started learning Python so I'm trying to avoid working too much in Python 2.  Currently learning GUI elements with wxPython.  The Python 3 documentation doesn't have an introductory section yet so I'm using the Python 2 'getting started' documentation and converting to Python 3 where needed.

I'm currently at [this section](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#Adding_a_few_more_controls).  There is a section for wx.EVT_CHAR for event handling when a keypress is detected on the focused object.  I don't see a reference to it in the [comparison chart](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html), or in the [CommandEvent docs](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/CommandEvent.html#commandevent), or in the "events emmitted by this class" section of the [wx.TextCtrl docs](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/TextCtrl.html#textctrl).  I've been able to convert most other non-Python 3 code such as SizerFlags, but I can't find an equivalent for this.

This is what I'm working with.

```
import wx
class ExampleFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        baseSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Create an editable text field
        self.textfield = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        # Attach event handlers to text field
        # Event for when the text changes
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnChange, self.textfield)
        # Event for when a key is pressed, for example an arrow key should fire this event but not the EVT_TEXT event
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnKeyPress, self.textfield)

        # Create a button that will clear the textfield
        clearButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CLEAR, "Clear")
        # Attach event handler on the clearButton to call OnClear()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClear, clearButton)

        # Multiline text field for seeing the events fire
        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style= wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY )

        # Add items to frame sizer
        baseSizer.Add(self.textfield, wx.SizerFlags(0).Expand())
        baseSizer.Add(clearButton, wx.SizerFlags(0).Expand())
        baseSizer.Add(self.logger, wx.SizerFlags(1).Expand())

        # Set sizer for frame
        self.SetSizer(baseSizer)

        # Show 
        self.Show()

    def OnClear(self, e):
        # Clear all text entered into the textfield and return focus
        self.textfield.SetValue("")
        self.textfield.SetFocus()

    def OnChange(self, e):
        # Log every time this event is fired
        self.logger.AppendText("OnChange: " + e.GetString() + '\n')

    def OnKeyPress(self, e):
        # Log every key press in the textfield
        self.logger.AppendText("OnKeyPress: " + e.GetKeyCode() + '\n')

app = wx.App(False)
ExampleFrame(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

The `OnChange()` will fire every single time the text in textfield changes.  The `OnKeyPress` never fires.  If I did get it to fire though, I don't see a GetKeyCode() equivalent in the [CommandEvent methods summary](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/CommandEvent.html#method-summary-methods-summary).

EDIT:
Problem solved thanks to [Mike Driscoll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393194/mike-driscoll).  I implemented his change which was to change this:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnKeyPress, self.textfield)
```

to this:

```
self.textfield.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnKeyPress, self.textfield)
```

Also I had to add `e.Skip()` to the `OnKeyPress` function.  Otherwise it was logging the key, but not adding text to the textfield.  The other events were fine without `Skip()`ing to pass the event up the control tree to other listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just bound the event incorrectly in this case. You want

```
self.textfield.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnKeyPress, self.textfield)
```

instead of

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnKeyPress, self.textfield)
```

And here it is in context:

```
import wx
class ExampleFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        baseSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Create an editable text field
        self.textfield = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        # Attach event handlers to text field
        # Event for when the text changes
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.OnChange, self.textfield)
        # Event for when a key is pressed, for example an arrow key should fire this event but not the EVT_TEXT event
        self.textfield.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnKeyPress, self.textfield)

        # Create a button that will clear the textfield
        clearButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CLEAR, "Clear")
        # Attach event handler on the clearButton to call OnClear()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClear, clearButton)

        # Multiline text field for seeing the events fire
        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style= wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY )

        # Add items to frame sizer
        baseSizer.Add(self.textfield, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        baseSizer.Add(clearButton,0)
        baseSizer.Add(self.logger, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        # Set sizer for frame
        self.SetSizer(baseSizer)

        # Show 
        self.Show()

    def OnClear(self, e):
        # Clear all text entered into the textfield and return focus
        self.textfield.SetValue("")
        self.textfield.SetFocus()
        e.Skip()

    def OnChange(self, e):
        # Log every time this event is fired
        self.logger.AppendText("OnChange: " + e.GetString() + '\n')
        e.Skip()

    def OnKeyPress(self, e):
        # Log every key press in the textfield
        self.logger.AppendText("OnKeyPress: " + str(e.GetKeyCode()) + '\n')
        e.Skip()

app = wx.App(False)
ExampleFrame(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

You will probably want to read the following wiki entry on the difference binding methods:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind

As for your other question, while I can't be certain, I would be very surprised if OnKeyPress didn't exist in Phoenix. I would give that a try even if it isn't in the documentation as I would guess it's still in there.

Comment: Wonderful.  The event.GetKeyCode() function worked correctly when it was fired from a EVT_CHAR event.  It threw errors when I tried to output it in response to a EVT_TEXT event.  Big thanks for that link about the different binding methods.  Apparently it **WAS** firing the EVT_CHAR event but that specific event doesn't propagate itself up the control tree.  So it was firing when a key was pressed, the event was satisfied, but my listener was listening in a place that would never receive it.  The link tried to convolute that for some reason with stories about fruits and kids or something.

Comment: Yeah, the story helps some people get their head around the concept...but it doesn't help everyone.